# jq: error (at output.json:0): object ({"apps":{...) and null (null) cannot be multiplied can't merge two json files

Tags: json, jq

I have two json files which I need to merge but when I run

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' web-apps.json android-apps.json | tee output.json
```

command I get the following error.

```
jq: error (at output.json:0): object ({"apps":{...) and null (null) cannot be multiplied
```

Here are my json files.

`web-apps.json`

```
{
  "apps": {
    "app1": [
      "v1.0"
    ],
    "app2": [
      "v3.7.2"
    ]
 }
}
```

`android-apps.json`

```
{
  "apps": {
    "mob-app1": [
      "v2.0"
    ],
    "mob-app2": [
      "v2.1"
    ]
 }
}
```

The expected output:

```
{
  "apps": {
    "app1": [
      "v1.0"
    ],
    "app2": [
      "v3.7.2"
    ],
   "mob-app1": [
      "v2.0"
    ],
   "mob-app2": [
     "v2.1"
   ]
 }
}
```

I don't understand what null means in this context. Both json files have the exact same structure/format and this is also the format I need.

Please ask for more details if needed.

EDIT: I referenced the wrong json file with a similar name.

Comment: Hi, it works for me. Are you sure your filenames are correct?

Comment: Please add the output of `jq --version`

Comment: [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VZ1GIjedDI)

Comment: @lojza You're right. I had both `android-apps.json` and `android-app.json` file and I referenced the wrong one. `android-apps.json` is indeed empty and I should've referenced the other one.

Comment: So this question can and should be closed, because it was caused by a typo and is not reproducible (nor helpful for future visitors).